# how find link by using date in oddsportal using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need a solution for this question  [oddsportal](https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/italy/serie-a/results/)  I need a particular date match names

```
Example: 

user input = 23 Jan 2022

output:

AC Milan - Juventus

Empoli - AS Roma

Napoli - Salernitana

Spezia - Sampdoria

Torino - Sassuolo

Cagliari - Fiorentina
```

don't take next date match names only needed user input date match names
like this I need Link

```
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'datet')]")
for i in dates:
    # print(i.text)
    if i.text == date:
        print(i.text)
        lin = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="tournamentTable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a')
        for link in lin:
            if i.text == date:
                print(link.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in **Java**

```
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(100));
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(50));
        driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/italy/serie-a/results/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        List<WebElement> dates = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr[class='center nob-border']"));
        List<WebElement> siblings;

        for (WebElement element: dates) {
            if ((element.findElement(By.cssSelector("th > span"))).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(userDate)){
                siblings=element.findElements(By.xpath("following-sibling::tr"));
                for (int i=1; i< siblings.size() ; i++ ){
                    try {
                        WebElement item = siblings.get(i).findElement(By.cssSelector("td[class='name table-participant'] > a"));
                        if (!(item.isDisplayed())) {
                            break;
                        } else
                            System.out.println(" " + item.getText());
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

**Solution:** find the date first then iterate siblings of it till next date.